# TYPO3: felogin on every page

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I want the user to be able to login on every page so I added the "felogin" login form in my header.

This is the html form that is generated by the felogin extension. I pasted it as it is my header:

```
<form onsubmit="; return true;" method="post" target="_top" action="/login.html">
    <input id="user" type="text" value="" placeholder="E-Mail*" name="user">
    <input id="pass" type="password" data-rsa-encryption="" value="" placeholder="Passwort*" name="pass">
    <input type="submit" value="Anmelden" name="submit">

    <div class="felogin-hidden">
        <input type="hidden" value="login" name="logintype">
        <input type="hidden" value="12" name="pid">
        <input type="hidden" value="/home.html" name="redirect_url">
        <input type="hidden" value="0" name="tx_felogin_pi1[noredirect]">
    </div>
</form>
```

The login does only work when I am on the login.html page, which is where the felogin plugin is located. If I try to login on any other page, even with correct credentials it will redirect to the login.html page with a flash message saying that there was an error.
Is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: That will not work, I think. What templating system are you using? FLUIDTEMPLATE?

Comment: Yes, fluid template

Comment: I would also advise against this solution. The form will be change if user is logged in. To ensure your page will be cacheable, you should embed such feature via Ajax.

Comment: I did hide the form with fluid when the user is authenticated. The issue is that the login doesn't work on every page .. only on the login.html page. So I must be missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work, because the RSA-Library is included only on the login page (where you've placed the flogin-plugin)
On the login page you can find the code

```
<script src="/typo3/sysext/rsaauth/Resources/Public/JavaScript/RsaLibrary.js?1492536592" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/typo3/sysext/rsaauth/Resources/Public/JavaScript/RsaEncryption.js?1492536592" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I also have realized the login form in the header. I see 2 solutions:
1) RSA-library should be included global
2) don't use the RSA encryption.

How do you place the login form in the header? With typoscript? Can I see your code?

Comment: I didn't use typoscript for the form. I simply pasted the html into my Header template. You are right, the javascript is missing, I will try to disable RSA or include the RSA javascript

Comment: It is suggested to use HTTPS instead of the custom `rsaauth` system extension which encrypts only user credentials when being submitted to the server system.

Answer (score 2):

you should copy the login object into a lib.login typoscript object

```
lib.login < plugin.tx_felogin_pi1
lib.login{
 //add here all configuration via typoscript
storagePid = ...
showForgotPasswordLink = ...
redirectMode = ...
...
}
```

and then use it in your page

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.login"/>
```

Please note that AFAIK your login page could have problems because you put the login form twice on the same page. you could remove lib.login in that page.

Answer (score 1):

if you can absolutely ensure that the website is *always* delivered via HTTPS, you can disable RSA

Answer (score 0):

you should customize you templates, otherwise you will have problems with same element ids, like id="user" id="pass"